# Setting ArcPy environment param takes long time

Tags: arcpy, performance, scratch-workspace, vmware

I am facing some performance issue with this code running on ArcPy from ArcMap (so Python 2.7):

```
import arcpy
import time
start = time.time()
arcpy.env.scratchWorkspace = 'c:/Temp/scratchoutput.gdb'
end = time.time()
print(end-start)
```

This code takes only 4-5s to excute on my old machine (Windows 7, 16Gb RAM, 4 cores). On my new machine (Windows 10, 32Gb RAM, 4 Cores (same Intel 8168 @2.7GHz) this script takes roughly 200-300s.

The new machine is using VMWares AppVolumes, whereas the old machine was a plain vanilla virtual machine, as it was mention by my Hardware team.

Has someone encountered similar problems?
A snapshot shows, that reading the registry takes ages for each key. The normal time should be around 0.000001s.
[image: registry operations captured with procMon]
The script opens up roughly 1Million of these key with a RegEnumKey Operation.

Comment: 2-300 seconds? 4-5 minutes to set the scratchWorkspace? Something is not right. I'm not sure if that call does any validation; even if it does, it shouldn't take that long. Have you tried running another command as your first thing to do? Like is it ONLY setting this workspace which is slow, or could it be any arcpy command?

Comment: Just a thought, is there anyway you can replace the scratch workspace with in-memory objects? This will significantly speed up your entire workflow, assuming your datasets are not too large for your RAM. More details: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/analysis/geoprocessing/basics/the-in-memory-workspace.htm

Comment: a second call of the same command to switch the workspace to something like "c:/Temp/scratchoutput2.gdb" took only 0.01s. There is no validation of the string nor any creation of a folder or a fgdb.